# How do I add login functionality (username/password) to my app with CSV

Tags: ruby, csv

Ruby newbie here. Basically I've got several users in a CSV file (headers below):

```
first_name,age,location,gender,phone_number,email,username,password
```

I want user's to login with their username which will check the CSV file for the corresponding username, and when it finds the username it will ask the user for the password, if the passwords match then it will run the 'user_mainmenu' variable which then takes the user to the User Main Menu.

```
def user_login
print "Enter username: "
  username_access = $stdin.gets.chomp
  CSV.foreach('users.csv', headers: true) do |row|
   if row["@username"] == username_access then
     @user = User.new(row.to_hash)
     break
   end
  end
print "Enter password: "
password_access = $stdin.gets.chomp
CSV.foreach('users.csv', headers: true) do |row|
  if row["@password"] == password_access then
    user_mainmenu
    break
  end
end
end
```

I'm pretty sure I'm not using the right code, I'm just using Ruby (not allowed to use Rails as its in a course and we are learning that later).
I can't find any answers anywhere as most involve Rails.

Apologies if there isn't enough info or if I'm not being clear enough, first time posting on here.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to read a CSV file twice. Using [`CSV#open`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open) and [`CSV::Table#new`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html#method-c-new), one might get the data in handy format into memory:

```
def user_login
  # load CSV
  csv = CSV::Table.new(CSV.open('users.csv', headers: true))

  print "Enter username: "
  username_access = $stdin.gets.chomp
  # detect row with this username
  row = csv.detect { |e| e["username"] == username_access }
  # immediately throw if no such user
  raise "No such user" unless row

  print "Enter password: "
  password_access = $stdin.gets.chomp
  raise "Wrong password" unless row["password"] == password_access

  # everything is fine, logged in, return user
  User.new(row.to_hash)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like your's is the more simplified version of mine with a few changes.

Answer (score 0):

Had a mentor help me:

```
def user_login
login_start
verified(gets.chomp)
end

def verified(input)
user_row = authentication(input)
if user_row
  puts 'Please enter your password:'
  print "> "
  password = gets.chomp
  if user_row['password'] == password
    user_mainmenu
  else
    puts "Incorrect password."
    sleep 1
    user_login
  end
else
  failed
end
end

def authentication(username)
CSV.open('users.csv', headers: true).find { |row| row['username'] == username }
end

def failed
puts "Username not recognised. Please try again."
sleep(1)
user_login
end

def login_start
puts "Enter username:"
print "> "
end
```

Comment: Great that you include your own answer and don't just let the Question "die" after you found a solution. Good spirit! And now ... let your mentor teach you how to format and indent the code ;)